# slashed effect preventing me from scrolling with fullpagejs any ideas please?

Tags: html, css, fullpage.js

Hello I am having a problem with navigating throw sections using fullpage.js and slashed css text effect. What I want to do is have a section with a slashed effect title in the middle and be able to scroll to the other section under it which also includes a slashed effect title.
In short I can't scroll down even with more div tags and sections.

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/fullpage.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/fullpage.min.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="section" id="box">
            <div class="slashed">

                <div class="top" title="Wow"></div>
                <div class="bot" title="Wow"></div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="section" id="box">
            <div class="slashed">

                <div class="top" title="Tell"></div>
                <div class="bot" title="Tell"></div>

            </div>
        </div>



    </div>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#wrapper').fullpage();
        });

    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
    #box{
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-5deg);
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden
}


html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}
body {

  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, #dc143c, #580818);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, #dc143c, #580818);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(center, #dc143c, #580818);
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, #dc143c, #580818);
  background: radial-gradient(center, #dc143c, #580818);
}
.slashed {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.slashed .top,
.slashed .bot {
  text-align: center;
  font: 62px/100px arial;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
}
.slashed .top:before,
.slashed .bot:before {
  content: attr(title);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(5deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(5deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(5deg);
  transform: rotate(5deg);
}
.slashed .top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 5px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 50%;
}
.slashed .top:before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -50px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.slashed .bot {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 0;
}
.slashed .bot:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

I would appreciate any help!! 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the code -- I'm having trouble reproducing this myself -- could you throw this in a tool like Codepen so that we can better help you?

Thanks!

Comment: @MathiasRechtzigel here : https://codepen.io/HyburdzMC/pen/QZxLrr                   If you open the settings for js and css you will see an external link for the fullpage.min.js and fullpage.min.css     just let me know I forgot to include anything